# My basic hyperlink tag isn't working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a simple website, as I'm a beginner programmer. I inserted a `<p>` tag, which worked all fine and dandy. There was two words in the paragraph which I wanted to link to a different page on my website, and it decided it didn't want to work. I don't know why it didn't work, because I have `<div>` tags in the same document to the same page that were working fine.

Edit: To define what wasn't working: It wasn't clickable. It changed color, like a normal hyperlink tag should, but was just a piece of text. You just couldn't click it. Even tags with an invalid or nonexistent href should be clickable. Right? Maybe I'm wrong, again, I am a beginner.

The other strange thing was that in my CSS file, I had the text-decoration set to none, so it shouldn't have changed color in the first place.

CSS:

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

This is the HTML that I had an issue with:

```
<p id="p1">Ingsoc is the Newspeak word for English Socialism. (For more on Newspeak, see the <a href="TruthPage.html">Ministry of Truth</a> page.)</p>
```

And here's an example of a link with the same destination that worked just fine:

```
<a href="TruthPage.html">
<div id="minitrue">Ministry of Truth</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: The html you posted looks fine. If you have the actual code that was failing, it would be a lot more helpful than what you did post.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code, as we are unable to assist you (it will be just guess work).

Comment: With the only part of code you are showing I can see two errors.

**1 -** the actual page were your <a> tag is pointing does not exist.
**2 -** You have a "non-closing" tag some where and it could make an error with your <a> tag. Double-check your document.

Can you post all your HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 
`<a href="DifferentPage.html">`

try
`<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/folderpath/DifferentPage.html">`

where 'yoursite.com' and 'folderpath' are changed to match your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me.  You could try...

```
<p />
<div>This is just basic text that was doing what it was supposed to. <a href="DifferentPage.html">This was the text</a> that I wanted to link to a different page.
</div>
```

if it's working within a div tag

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `href="DifferentPage.html"` is not vailid. My suggestion is to open that other page on your site, then copy the location in the address bar.